# Can’t Browse SMB Share After Temporary Outage

Tags: windows, macos, network-shares, smb

This is a strange issue that I’ve not seen before, but maybe somebody here could help?

I have a Mac (running Snow Leopard) that is a SMB client accessing a Windows 7 share. The Windows 7 server has some networking issues though and can drop connection to the network for a few minutes, then is back up and working. This is because I have a junky USB WiFi adapter.

Generally the Mac has no issues connecting to the win7 server. Occasionally when the Windows 7 server connection drops, if the mac was connected before hand it is unable to reconnect / browse a still mounted share when the server comes back online. If I try to browse, finder just sits there acting if it’s trying to read, or if I’ve unmounted the shares, then the *Connect to Server* dialog just sits there and spins while any other network resources are still accessible. The Windows 7 server is also accessible from other windows clients as well (so no fault of the server other than losing connection). The only way to fix this connection issue with OSX is a reboot.

My question is: is there a way I can force OSX to drop the connection or manage it so that finder doesn’t have these issues when connected to my server? I was thinking of a simple script to unmount the server shares after X amount of time they spend inactive (not being accessed). This would help the intermittent drops when it’s not in use, but wouldn’t help if the connection drops while streaming content from the server, so a reboot would still be necessary at time.

Any suggestions would be welcome. If you need any more information about either computer network setup, feel free to ask and I’ll get back to you as quick as I can.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I've heard that you need OSX Lion or later. There were some file sharing issues reported. I found a straightforward tutorial for sharing files between osx and win7: http://macs.about.com/od/filesharing/ss/file-sharing-with-snow-leopard-win7.htm -- or try this "samba manager" http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41541/smbup -- you could also try to use macports and a newer version of samba: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120401160655922 (or just use Unix/Linux such as Ubuntu)

Comment: Mediageek, thank you for the info, but the problem is not with the Mac being a server, but the Mac accessing a server (SMB or Windows Share, however you want to call it).

When the Mac has a windows share mounted, and the windows share goes offline temporarily, the Mac is unable to reconnect once the share comes back online without rebooting the Mac.